# Are Adafruit RGB 30 LED/m flexi-strips suitable to wear in large numbers?

Tags: led, led-strip, wearable

I am working on a project that involves using a large number of LEDs on a single garment. According to my initial design, I would need as much as 1800 RGB LEDs. I have seen these LED strips from Adafruit https://www.adafruit.com/product/285. Since the strips draws <strike>60mA</strike> 600mA per meter, and I would need roughly 60 meters, this amounts to a total of 36 amps. Using them would imply (I guess) either using dangerously high amps or distributing the current by using unacceptable numbers of battery packs. My questions are therefore:

1. I am correct in my assertion that using the LED strips linked to above is not realistic (i.e. 1800 ish LEDs on a single garment)? Or can I overcome this problem in any other way, as for instance by setting software limits to the PWN controlling the LEDs, thus limiting the current flowing through them?
2. Are there any other types of LEDs that would be more suitable? They need to be easily controlled by a microcontroller without additional circuitry, and ideally RGB.

---

(Updated text to show the maximum "current per meter" value, 600mA per meter, quoted on that Adafruit page, instead of the originally written value of 60mA per meter; this change has affected answers.)

Comment: What does ada say? What does the data sheet say? Does it have a data sheet? How many watts have you calculated? How dark are the sunglasses to be worn by the rapidly overheating person inside the suit. Voting to close because of no research, not data sheet links and asking questions about off-the-shelf electronic products.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of many reasons listed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Sam caught an error by the OP which changes my answer.

You will need to supply a total of 36 amps if you turn everything on a once. But this might be a bit boring because you will just look like a large white light bulb. Consider adding a small programmable controller that cycles through various colors and turns sections on and off to make it more interesting. This will also greatly reduce the energy that your battery will need to supply.

To help you with your battery calculations, if you had 1/3 of the LEDs turned on at any one time on the average, you would then only need ~12 amps.  Battery life is expressed in amp-hours so a 12 amp-hour battery would power your LEDs for 1 hour. If you used a commonly available 7 Ah battery, this would power them for less than 1/2 hour.

The app notes indicate that the strips will work with 9 volts. If you used a 12 volt battery with a 12 volt to 9 volt buck converter, you could extend your battery life by at least 15%. The LEDs would be slightly dimmer but it may be worth it for the extra life. You could also consider Li Ion cells that add up to a voltage lower than 12 volts.

Do break your LED strings into strips that draw no more than ~4 amps each and put a 5 amp fuse in series with each such strip from the battery to head off a potential clothing fire. Monitor your battery temperature when in use to make sure it is not getting hot. Always charge your battery away from the clothing in a safe fashion.

Have fun with the project.

Comment: Although the OP's text is indeed partly wrong (I'll edit it now to fix it) the later maths is correct :-( The Adafruit page says that the LED strip requires a maximum 0.6A (i.e. 600mA) per meter (60mA max per 100mm "segment") so the total max current does seem to be 36A (!) which affects your answer :-(

Comment: @SamGibson Good catch, Sam. I will (severely) edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the Adafruit datasheet says,

> "Max 0.6 Amps per meter (all LEDs lit full brightness)"

So the fear of OP might be valid.

However, if the controller is smart enough and limit light patterns, maybe more reasonable consumption can be achieved. In my experience, a high-efficiency LEDs can output pretty intense light running at 2 mA.

If the strip really is useful at 60 mA per 30 LEDs (as Adafruit says), this project will take 3-4 A total, as Glenn noted. Then, with a 12V boost converter, this will translate into 10-12A at a single-cell Li-Ion battery. So even a **single** [high-discharge (~5C) 18650 battery](https://www.powerstream.com/18650-high-discharge-rate.htm) can lit the thing up for 10-20 minutes. Three such cells in series will power the project directly for about an hour.

There are [flat batteries](http://www.lipolbattery.com/high%20rate%20discharge%20lithium%20polymer%20battery.html), 5-7mm thick, up to 20000 mAh capacity and 8C discharge rate, they will last longer.

ADDITION: if money and design effort time is not a problem, there are tiny FPGA chips designed specifically to drive a single RGB LED, 1.4x1.4mm in size, 16-ball WLCSP, [iCE40 series from Lattics Semi](http://www.latticesemi.com/Products/FPGAandCPLD/iCE40Ultra.aspx). You can use some serial interface and control everything in any desired way.

ADDITION2: To illustrate how overstated the 20 mA "requirement" is (or how low quality the strip LEDs are): in one project I was using an OSRAM RGB LED, in PLCC-6 package, 3.2x3.2mm,  P/N LRTBGFTG-T7AW-1+V7A7-29+R. To get a light that would not blind an eye, I had to use ~0.7 mA (!!!) on Green, and 1.6-1.7 mA on Red and Blue.

Comment: *"If the strip really is useful at 60 mA per 30 LEDs (as Adafruit says)"* Just to be clear, can you give a reference for that current requirement? On the Adafruit page, I can see (max) "0.6 Amps per meter" where 1 meter is 30 LEDs, so that doesn't match the quote. And I can see (max) "60mA draw per strip segment" (where a "strip segment" is 100mm, i.e. 1/10 of a meter) so again 0.6A per meter, which doesn't match the quote. I can't find anywhere that says 60mA per 30 LEDs. Did you find something that I didn't? Or were you misled by the OP's original mention of 60mA per meter too? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson, yep, you are again right. The Adafruit says 3 RGB per SEGMENT of 100 mm. They quote 20 mA per 3 LEDs (in series), or 60 mA for RGB. Finally they say "1.2 A per meter". However, as I said, I rarely seen a modern LED fed by 20 mA. If a reasonable light output needs 20 mA, then this is a really old shitty LED technology. More, the entire strip offer looks fishy, you can't feed amperes of current along the series skinny flexible segments. And all 3 LEDs in a segment will lit up at once. Still I am of strong opinion that the strip should be usable at 1/10th of the quoted power.

Comment: *Finally they say "1.2 A per meter".* I didn't find that figure (again, perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place) but I completely agree that the quoted maximum by Adafruit is just that, a maximum, and hopefully it should be usable on a lower current. I only asked as I couldn't find the specific earlier quote. :-) Even driven at 1/10th the max power, I'm wondering about having 60m of the LED strip *on a garment*, as the OP states, but I can't see a "kg per meter" figure to estimate the total weight. Anyway, that's a different concern. :-) Thanks for your reply & clarification.

Comment: @SamGibson, I saw this 1.2 A/m quote somewhere in their design example...wait, here: https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-led-strips/current-draw

Answer (score 0):

> I am correct in my assertion that using the LED strips linked to above
>   is not realistic (i.e. 1800 ish LEDs on a single garment)? Or can I
>   overcome this problem in any other way, as for instance by setting
>   software limits to the PWN controlling the LEDs, thus limiting the
>   current flowing through them?

Yes, that power consumption is unrealistic assuming you want them on for any length of time rather than brief flashes.

Yes, you could PWM them and so reduce both the brightness and the power consumption.

Keep in mind that the maximum power is for them on full brightness white, other colours will be lower power since they won't require all 3 colour LEDs to be on. So a 50% PWM in red would be about 1/6th of the power consumption.

However you're still looking at a lot of power consumption no matter what you do.

> Are there any other types of LEDs that would be more suitable? They need to be easily controlled by a microcontroller without additional circuitry, and ideally RGB.

1) Those need additional circuitry, they are 9-12V so at the very least you need a FET controlled by the microcontroller.
2) Not really. Less or dimmer LEDs will reduce your power but ultimately LED power isn't that variable, for the same brightness you'll be looking at roughly the same power level no matter what type of LED you use.

You could look at a completely different technology like Electroluminescent wires [here](https://www.adafruit.com/category/50) or for an animated effect [here](http://elwirecraft.co.uk/el-products/chasing-el-wire/ultra-chasing-el-wire-tri-colour/), whether it's suitible depends on the effect that you are trying to produce. It's often easier to incorporate into clothing then LEDs but isn't as bright, not as easy to vary the brightness of and the only way to get multiple colours would be to run multiple threads next to each other.